# C# "Load" an object's property with text from a file during compilation

Tags: c#, compilation

I want to load text from a file into a property on a class *during compilation*.

Example -

I have a file called **banana.txt**, the contents of which I'd like to put into a `Banana` class during compilation.

```
public class Banana
{
     public string Text { get; set; }  //contents of banana.txt goes in here
}
```

How can this be done?

The purpose of this is so every time a `Banana` object's `Text` is needed, the file does not have to be read, the text from the file will only have to be read once during compile time.

(**NOTE**: I *must* read from the file, not copy the contents into a variable, or resource file. And I realize every `Banana` object will have the same text.)

Comment: Is it OK to load the file just once on application startup (runtime)?

Comment: Ashin, That would be a better solution than loading it every time the object is called.

Comment: please check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be: 
Write a pre-build event. 
In the pre-build event, invoke a program. 
This program can be another C# program
This program would read from banana.txt.
Then this program would re-generate your source code.

for eg. if you have your code as:

```
public string Text = "~placeholder_for_Text~"
```

the program would replace the "~placeholder_for_Text~" with the actual contents of banana.txt

Answer (score 0):

If it's alright to load the file content just once at runtime, you may consider using the following code:

```
public class Banana
{
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return fileContent;
        }
    }

    private static string fileContent;

    static Banana()
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("banana.txt"))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ashin, I may end up using something like this, but I would still like to know if there's a simple way to do it in code during compilation.